# Angular: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angularjs, heroku, cross-domain, ionic-framework

I've read alot of the same or similar questions and almost all the answers is to configure the server.
My client app is `Angular.js` `"ionic"` my server app is `node.js` and deployed on `Heroku`.
here is my server configuration:

```
// set up CORS resource sharing
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
})
```

note: my client were normally communicate with the server when i run the server locally

my client app fail to make any http request and am getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myheroku.herokuapp.com/api/x. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
```

Here is the request header:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6,fi;q=0.4,it;q=0.2,en-GB;q=0.2,en-CA;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:myheroku.herokuapp.com
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Referer:http://localhost:8100/
```

Comment: Is that ``app.use()`` before or after ``app.method('/api/x', ...)``? It should be before.

Comment: Yes sure, and as i mentioned it was working all fine locally.

Comment: Well, locally it shouldn't require CORS unless they were on different ports. Can you share what the HTTP request headers were?

Comment: They were running on different ports and, ill add the Request header to the question

Comment: What is the method though? Is it GET?

Comment: yes, all the methods am testing for now is GET. here is one of my end points code:
app.get('/api/items/xx', function(req, res) {
  Item.find({category: 'yy'},function(err, items) {
    res.send(items);
  });
})

Answer (score 0):

Am sorry if it's a silly mistake but maybe it will be useful for beginners like me.
i checked my server app logs `heroku logs` and found this

```
heroku process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

and since heroku assign the port to the app this how i fixed this issue:
From:

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('App listeining on', server.address().port);
})
```

To:

```
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, function(){
    console.log('App listeining on', server.address().port);
})
```